# Temporary Tables Not Working in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I run this query

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE usercount SELECT * FROM users
```

I get this message

```
Your SQL query has been executed successfully ( Query took 0.1471 sec )
```

But when I try to access the newly created table using

```
SELECT * FROM usercount
```

I get this error

```
#1146 - Table 'abc_site.usercount' doesn't exist
```

Not sure why, I need to mention that I've did a good share of googling beforehand.

My version of PHPMyAdmin is 3.5.2.2 and MySQL 5.5.27

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PHPMyAdmin (or rather PHP) closes the database connection after each screen. Thus your temporary tables disappear.

You can put multiple SQL statements in the SQL query box in PHPMyAdmin; this should be executed as one block and thus the temporary table is not deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary tables are temparar and after use thay Delete.
 for example ,when insert data into database , first we can insert into temp table and thus when complete transaction , then insert into main table.

```
EXAMPLE :
//------------------------------------------
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP
(
USERNAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PASSWORD VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
EMAIL varchar(100),
TYPE_USER INT
);
INSERT INTO TEMP VALUES('A','A','A','1');
SELECT * FROM TEMP
//-----------------------------------------
Show A,A,A,1
```

Comment: This is not working.  showing same result:     SELECT * FROM TEMP
 LIMIT 0, 25 
MySQL said: Documentation

#1146 - Table 'test.temp' doesn't exist