# MYSQL error on a simple SELECT

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, temporary

Can someone tell my why this code...

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS parent;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE parent (id INT);
INSERT INTO parent VALUES (1);
SELECT * FROM parent;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE parent;
```

results in this error (on the SELECT line)...

```
Table 'sarumcom_cypo.parent' doesn't exist
```

'sarumcom_cypo' is my database. I have tried variations of this code: with and without the word TEMPORARY, starting with a "USE sarumcom_cypo" line, with a different table name, and with the database name prefixing all references to parent. In all cases I get the error.

If I remove the SELECT, there are no errors. The INSERT reports "# 1 row affected", and the final DROP reports "# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)".

I am using phpMyAdmin to run this code.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14426401 and consider a different strategy for testing with phpmyadmin. Such as a stored proc or your real php program.

Comment: Thanks @Drew, do your comments suggest you think there's something unreliable about the phpMyAdmin environment? As I am running all statements as a script within in the one client session, the db connection should still be alive and the temp table should still be there when the SELECT is performed.

Comment: It would be unfair for me to say that. But I can say that I would not program with it. Granted, there are times when in hosting environments there is often little choice. I do seem to think your connection is gone and poof goes the Temp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary tables will be deleted when the current client session terminates.

Comment: Thanks @Ashok, but I am running the entire  script in the one session.